# Is there a way to know the domain attached to a cookie on the server site?

Tags: apache, http, cookies, cgi, rfc

I am writing an Apache [CGI in C++](http://snapwebsites.org) and looking at the cookies (HTTP_COOKIE environment variable), I get a list of `name=value` separated by semi-colons, but none of the flags coming with each cookie.

So if I have two cookies defined as follow:

```
my_cookie=123; Path=/; Domain=.snap.website
my_cookie=789; Path=/; Domain=.test.snap.website
```

I do not know which one has domain `.snap.website` and which has domain `.test.snap.website`. Yet, from [RFC 2965, point 3.3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965#page-11),(and [RFC 2109, point 4.3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109#page-9) for `Set-Cookie`) it looks like the browsers are expected to send all of that information to the server.

Would there be a way for my CGI script to get at least the domain name for each cookie?

#### Update

What I want to know is whether the server gets all the information when the browser sends a POST or a GET request. The data shown above is what the browser has. However, according to the comment from Ahmad Bilal, I can see that the browser is not actually expected to send all the information, only a list of name/value pairs.

```
cookie-header = "Cookie:" OWS cookie-string OWS
cookie-string = cookie-pair *( ";" SP cookie-pair )
cookie-pair   = cookie-name "=" cookie-value
cookie-name   = token
cookie-value  = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )
cookie-octet  = %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-3A / %x3C-5B / %x5D-7E
```

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.2.1

So unfortunately the server cannot know whether a cookie with a given name is attached to this or that specific domain and/or path.

Comment: The RFC 2965 has been depreciated, instead [look at RFC6265](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265)

Comment: What browser are you using? I can perfectly see the proper domain for each cookie in latest Firefox.

Comment: @AhmadBilal, note that I am talking about the server side. From RFC6265 as referenced by you earlier, it looks like that data does NOT get sent back to the server.

Comment: Ah! I see, server side.. then..are you using a array to set both cookies? or two separate strings?

Comment: I feel you ought to explain more, I feel the question is lacking important details. Like, how are you originally setting the cookies (preparing and then sending to client), and then how do you query for cookies on server side?

Comment: Use wireshark and inspect the http requests.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni, note that an older RFC included the cookies, but RFC6265 (as referenced by Ahmad Bilal), which is the latest, does not. This is the answer I was looking for but Ahmad did not write an actual answer I could give him a +1 and checkmark...